# retrieve current parameter value in Rails controller - Error: Couldn't find Question without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

Upon clicking delete I want my page to redirect to the current user's poll. This something like this.
questions_controller.rb:

```
  def destroy
    @poll_id = Question.find(param[:poll_id])
    @question.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_poll_url(current_user.id, @question.poll_id), notice: "Question was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The Questions_controller's content is the same as the rails generated with the exception of the above change.

the question_controller has the poll_id as a paramter. How do I retrieve it's current value to use for redirection.

```
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:poll_id, :title, :description)
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users do
    resources :polls
  end
  resource :polls do
    resources :questions 
  end
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in QuestionsController#destroy
Couldn't find Question without an ID

Extracted source (around line #52):           
  # DELETE /questions/1 or /questions/1.json
  def destroy
    @poll_id = Question.find(param[:poll_id])
    session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
    @question.destroy
```

with line 52 being `@poll_id = Question.find(param[:poll_id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`param[:poll_id]` is not correct. You always get these attributes in the controller in the method named `params` and as we submit a form from the front end Rails maps them to a specific key (name of the model singular), for example, to get the `poll_id` you need to use:

```
question_params[:poll_id]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
params[:question][:poll_id]
```

Also not sure if you `poll_id` would equal to the `id` saved in `questions` table. The `find` method would always find by `id` which means that:

```
Question.find(param[:poll_id])
```

means

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = param[:poll_id]
```

So if `poll_id` is equivalent to `id` then that is fine or you may want to replace `find` by `find_by` or you can also use `params[:id]` instead of `poll_id` if that exists (depends on your routes).

More information here on params: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Comment: to replace find by find_by worked